# How to use \processifversion in Latex

Tags: multiple-files

I am using the `\processifversion{tag}` to create various versions of report. I have two questions on how to use this command or its equivalent `\begin{tag} ... \end{tag}`:

In a table, I wanted to pick up a specific line for a "tag" using "`\processifversion{tag}{a & b & c \\\hline}`", but got error message "`Missing } inserted`". How to have `\processifversion` work together with table (`tabular` environment)?

I intended to use  `\processifversion{tag1, tag2}{TEXT}` to include "TEXT" when tag1 or tag2 is included. However, I found with this, "TEXT" is always included even tag1 and tag2 are both excluded. How to fix this?

I added the following simple sample. This code works. However, if I want to output "Hello PDF world!" by turn on either "PDF1" and "PDF2", what is the most efficient way to do it?

The real case I am working is more complicated: 1. I need to output 8 different versions, where some versions may have common part; 2. the common part could be very lengthy. So it may not be reasonable to repeat the common part for each tag.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\author{Al Alexander}
\title{}

\usepackage{versions}
\includeversion{PDF}
\excludeversion{HTML}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

% if "PDF" has been included, do this:
\processifversion{PDF}{Hello PDF world!}

% if "HTML" has been included, do this:
\processifversion{HTML}{Hello HTML world!}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, make a minimal example, in particular do mention the packages you're using. There are thousands of them and it's likely that just a few here have ever heard about `\processifversion`. I didn't, for instance.

Comment: Here is a short sample: \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\author{Al Alexander}
\title{}

\usepackage{versions}
\includeversion{PDF}
\excludeversion{HTML}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

% if "PDF" has been included, do this:
\processifversion{PDF}{Hello PDF world!}

% if "HTML" has been included, do this:
\processifversion{HTML}{Hello HTML world!}

\end{document}

Comment: Please, add the code to your question.